# interface factoring / interface design in .NET

Tags: c#, interface, components

I want to design a internal framework made up of several loosely coupled components.

In a book I found the advice to prefer implementing several interfaces by a concrete class and not to build interface trees.

Example for a data access interface (family):

My approach:

```
interface ISession : IDisposable
{
    void OpenSession();
    void CloseSession();
}

interface IDataAccess: ISession
{
    void SetData(string data);
    string GetData();
}

class MyTextFileAccess : IDataAccess 
{
    // no-op Open, Close, Dispose
}

class SQLDataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    // all interface methods are really needed
}
```

The approach which seems to be favoured in the book would probably look like this:

```
interface ISession
{
    void OpenSession();
    void CloseSession();
}

interface IDataAccess
{
    void SetData(string data);
    string GetData();
}


class MyTextFileAccess : IDataAccess 
{
    // don't have to implement unused interface methods
}

class SQLDataAccess : IDataAccess, IDisposable, ISession
{
    // same as above
}
```

The usage of the interfaces would also differ:

```
void UseMyWay(IDataAccess da) // IDataAccess inherits from ISession and IDisposable
{
    da.OpenSession();
    da.GetData();
    da.SetData("");
    da.CloseSession();

    da.Dispose();
}
void UseTheBooksWay(IDataAccess da) // IDataAccess doesn't inherit from ISession and IDisposable
{
    var da_session = da as ISession;
    var da_disposable  = da as IDisposable;

    if (da_session != null)
        da_session.OpenSession();
    da.GetData();
    da.SetData("");
    if (da_session != null)
        da_session.CloseSession();

    if (da_disposable != null)
    da_disposable.Dispose();
}
```

I prefer the usage in my approach, since it's uniform and the user doesn't have to think about testing for several interfaces (which are not obvious just by looking at `IDataAccess`) and thus can't forget to do so.

But I also prefer the concise interfaces devoted to only one topic used in the books way; This also has the advantage that I don't have to implement interfaces that are clearly not neccessary (text file access).
The "final" interface in my approach requires knowledge of all implementations which doesn't seem right since the interface should not depend upon the implementation details. This can be a problem if I want to add a new `SecureDataAccess` implementation which requires an authentication first.

Is there a way to combine both advantages, or are there other approaches you use?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say you are right or wrong and its probably circumstantial as to which one would be used. In the case of your approach if you implement IDataAccess you are required to implement ISession and IDisposable which is ok if you will always require that.

The other approach has advantages because you can use all 3 independently, making it more flexible. You can use IDataAccess and ISession without it having to implement IDiposable. I can't really tell you which you can and can't use as you should be weighing up advantages/disadvantages based on your scenario.

I suppose combining the 2 would mean within one project you have have some that have your approach and some with the books approach, personally I would use the books approach as if you come further down the line and need to use one without the other then it can become a problem for maintainability and, maybe, you could say your approach is going against your loosely coupled architecture.

Comment: I added my latest approach as another answer. I'd appreciate your opinion about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I've come up with so far:
It's extensible from the library side but also safe from the user side (which cannot know which interfaces are expected to also use (`ISession`, `IDisposable`...).

The main points:

- The primary idea is to have a class between consumer and library that defines the contract, e.g. which interfaces are available/have to be used.
- A `SQLDataAccess` won't be availbale if the contract doesn't include `ISession` and `IDisposable`.
- A client using an interface via this contract at least knows what interfaces are expected and has a chance to use them correctly.
- A `FileDataAccess` can use the "simple" contract `PlainDataAccess` and - with the help of some no-op implementations - the more advanced `SessionedDataAccess`.
- The `FileDataAccess` doesn't need to implement these interfaces itself.

Here's some sample code:

```
using System;
namespace InterfaceDesign
{

    // the interface we're really interested in
    public interface IDataAccess
    {
        string GetData();
        void SetData(string data);
    }

    // a requirement for SQLDataAccess
    public interface ISession
    {
        void OpenSession();
        void CloseSession();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This "interface for the consumer" is intended only for classes that have no special needs before/after accessing data
    /// </summary>
    public class PlainDataAccess
    {
        internal PlainDataAccess(IDataAccess dataAccess)
        {
            this.DataAccess = dataAccess;
        }
        public IDataAccess DataAccess { get; private set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This "interface for the consumer" is intended for classes that have only the special needs to open/close sessions and be disposed.
    /// </summary>
    public class SessionedDataAccess
    {
        public IDataAccess DataAccess { get; private set; }
        public ISession Session { get; private set; }
        public IDisposable Disposable { get; private set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Simplifies creation by not having to pass in the same variable 3 times
        /// </summary>
        internal static SessionedDataAccess Create<T>(T sessionedDataAccess) where T :IDataAccess, ISession, IDisposable
        {
            return new SessionedDataAccess(dataAccess: sessionedDataAccess , session: sessionedDataAccess , disposable: sessionedDataAccess);
        }

        private SessionedDataAccess(IDataAccess dataAccess, ISession session, IDisposable disposable)
        {
            this.DataAccess = dataAccess;
            this.Session = session;
            this.Disposable = disposable;
        }

        public  static SessionedDataAccess Create(PlainDataAccess dataAccess)
        {
            return new SessionedDataAccess(dataAccess: dataAccess.DataAccess, session: NoOpSession.Instance,
                disposable: NoOpDisposable.Instance);
        }

        private class NoOpSession : ISession
        {
            public static readonly ISession Instance = new NoOpSession();

            public void OpenSession()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no op session opened");
            }

            public void CloseSession()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no op session closed");
            }
        }
        private class NoOpDisposable : IDisposable
        {
            public static readonly IDisposable Instance = new NoOpDisposable();
            public void Dispose()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no op disposed");
            }
        }
    }

    // further "consumer interfaces" can be added. Extension methods provide easy promotions to more "demanding" interfaces by using no-op implementations.



    /// <summary>
    /// A sample class that has no special need for sessions etc.
    /// </summary>
    public class FileDataAccess : IDataAccess
    {
        private FileDataAccess()
        {
        }


        public static PlainDataAccess Create()
        {
            return new PlainDataAccess(dataAccess: new FileDataAccess());
        }

        public string GetData()
        {
            return "from file";
        }

        public void SetData(string data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("written to file");
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// A more complex data access requiring sessions
    /// </summary>
    public class SQLDataAccess : IDataAccess, ISession, IDisposable
    {
        private SQLDataAccess()
        {
        }


        public static SessionedDataAccess Create()
        {
            return SessionedDataAccess.Create(new SQLDataAccess());
        }


        public string GetData()
        {
            return "from sql";
        }

        public void SetData(string data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("written to SQL");
        }

        public void OpenSession()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("session opened");
        }

        public void CloseSession()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Session closed");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("disposed");
        }
    }




    public static class Extensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// allows to use a plain data access as a sessioned data access by providing no-op  ISession and IDisposable implementations
        /// </summary>
        public static SessionedDataAccess Promote(this PlainDataAccess self)
        {
            return SessionedDataAccess.Create(dataAccess: self);
        }
    }




    public class ConsumerExamples
    {
        public void Provider()
        {
            var fileAccess = FileDataAccess.Create();
            var sqlDataAccess = SQLDataAccess.Create();


            Consume1(sqlDataAccess);

            //Consume2(sqlDataAccess);  // this won't compile

            Consume1(fileAccess.Promote());
            Consume2(fileAccess);


        }



        /// <summary>
        /// This consumer is prepared to handle sessions.
        /// Can handle our sql data access and (after promotion) the basic file data access
        /// </summary>
        public void Consume1(SessionedDataAccess sessionedDataAccess)
        {
            sessionedDataAccess.Session.OpenSession();

            Console.WriteLine(
                sessionedDataAccess.DataAccess.GetData()
                );
            sessionedDataAccess.DataAccess.SetData("data");

            sessionedDataAccess.Session.CloseSession();
            sessionedDataAccess.Disposable.Dispose();
        }

        // can consume only file access

        /// <summary>
        /// This consumer is NOT prepared to handle sessions.
        /// It can only handle the file access.
        /// There is no way (without cheating) to pass in a SQL data access here
        /// </summary>
        public void Consume2(PlainDataAccess dataAccess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                dataAccess.DataAccess.GetData()
                );
            dataAccess.DataAccess.SetData("data");

        }

    }
}
```